# Scope of anonymous function passed as function argument

Tags: javascript, scope

Given the following code, what should I expect to see in the alert?

```
var a = 100;
function afunc(infunc){
  a = 10;
  infunc.call();
}

afunc(function(){alert(a)});
```

My initial thought was that my browser should alert 100 since the variable a=100 would be in scope for the anonymous function passed as an argument to afunc. But this assumes that the anonymous function is actually defined in the global context. Apparently that's not the case as the browser alerts 10. So why is a=10 ahead of a=100 in the scope chain?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you're setting a to 10 before you call the anonymous function. a is in fact global, but you're setting it to 10.

Answer (score 6):

> So why is a=10 ahead of a=100 in the scope chain?

It's not. You've only defined 1 `a` variable, which is simply being changed from `100` to `10` before being alerted.

If you want the `a`s to be distinct variables with their own values, they both need a `var` keyword:

```
var a = 100
function afunc(infunc){
  var a = 10;
  infunc.call();
}

afunc(function(){alert(a)})​
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following example:

```
var a = 100;

function afunc(infunc){
  a = 10;
  var f = function (){
    console.log(a);
  };
  f.call();
  infunc.call();
}

afunc(function (){ console.log(a); });
```

We assign a value of 10 to `a` within the scope of `afunc`, and then call two functions one after the other that simply log the value of `a`. In this case, you would expect both functions to log 10 as the value of `a`, and that's in fact what happens.

In your example, `infunc` will be executed in essentially the same scope as any local function defined in `afunc`, regardless of where it was actually defined. Since you assigned a value to `a` in a narrower scope, that's the value of `a` when you call `infunc`.

Functions *do* retain some scope from their definition, as in the following example:

```
function bfunc(){
  var b = 'hello';
  return function (){ console.log(b); };
}

afunc(bfunc());
```

Here, the anonymous function returned by `bfunc` is actually called from within the scope of `afunc`, but it's still able to log the correct value of `b` as it was assigned in the original scope. If you were to change `afunc` to assign a different value to `b`, it would still log `"hello"` because the `b` defined in `afunc` is a different variable than the `b` defined in `bfunc`.